# Wildfly 8.0.0 Logging login attempts for management console

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, wildfly-8

I use a wildfly 8.0.0. 
For security reasons i need logging login attempts for management console. Is it possible and how?

The wildfly instance is configured in standalone mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting under standalone.xml - management>audit-log - by default audit logging is disabled - so set enabled="true" -

```
<audit-log>
    <formatters>
        <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
    </formatters>
    <handlers>
        <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
    </handlers>
    <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="true">
        <handlers>
            <handler name="file"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
</audit-log>
```